# Suppose A1, A2, . . . have the same cardinality as R. (There are denumerably many of them.) What is the cardinality of A1 ×A2 ×···

Tags: cardinals

Suppose A1, A2, . . . have the same cardinality as R. (There are denumerably many of them.) What is the cardinality of A1 ×A2 ×···?

Not really sure how to approach this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if there were only the two listed $A$s: $A_1$ and $A_2$?  Then if there were only three?  Then if there were only four?  What do you get in the limit as the number of $A_i$ goes to (countable, since indexed by subset of integers) infinity?

Comment: If you are allowed to use basic cardinal arithmetic properties, then the set in question has cardinality $c \cdot c \cdot c \cdot \ldots$ (a countably infinite product), which equals ${\aleph_0} \cdot c \leq c \cdot c = c.$

Comment: i am not sure how to find what it would be as it approaches infinity. Would it still be R?

Comment: So in this case, it is still equal to R?

Comment: Possibly $0$, unless you're assuming the axiom of choice.